# IllegalArgumentException in grails, failed to evaluate expression 'ADMIN'

Tags: grails

I'm getting this error on each request in AdminController. The same happens with other Roles. I'm using Grails 3.2.9. If more details needed please comment below. Here is Role class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='authority')
@ToString(includes='authority', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    public static final String ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN = "SUPER_ADMIN"
    public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN"
    public static final String ROLE_COMPANY = "COMPANY"
    public static final String ROLE_PILOT = "PILOT"
    public static final String ROLE_MEMBER = "MEMBER"

    String authority

    Role(String authority) {
        this()
        this.authority = authority
    }

    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }
}
```

Here is the stack

2017-09-15 09:02:59.701 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'ADMIN'
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.groovy:57)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.groovy)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.checkOtherVoters(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.groovy:90)
at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'ADMIN' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:26)
... 64 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think that Roles have to start with ROLE_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent release bumped the version of the Spring Security jars to 4.0.x which changed the way the role name prefix is overridden. Your role names don't start with "ROLE_" so they're not detected as roles. Thus they're assumed to be a SpEL expression, and you're seeing a failure to evaluate `'ADMIN'` as an expression.

The straightforward workaround would be to rename all role names so they start with "ROLE_" until the plugin is again in sync with Spring Security.